# Chrome adds spaces to <p> tag when using <span>

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I wonder why Chrome keeps space characters inside `<p>   xxx   <span></span></p>` tag. Firefox doesn't add it.

Code example:
https://jsfiddle.net/8m1v9fyb/1/ (check on Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: Perhaps CSS? Can you click `<>` and post a [mcve]

Comment: Surely your styles can't be so fragile that an extra space breaks it?  If so, you probably want to rethink how you are doing it

Answer (score 1):

How does your source file look? Do you have spaces in it? If you write it in one line, without spaces, it probably fixes your problem.

```
<p>Zablokowana<span></span></p>
```

Comment: That's it, but why does Firefox parse it in different way, and how to make it work the same for every browser (without spaces)?

Comment: If you remove extra spaces, you should be fine. The problem is, Chrome takes some tabs and line breaks as additional spaces. So try to avoid them, when you want to display something and you should be fine in every browser.

Comment: It causes to write code in one line. I have found solution: adding CSS style `p { white-space: nowrap; }` helps.